# Two dimensional array passed to new Map fails in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Can't pass two dimensional array to `new Map` in Typescript:

```
 const myArray: string[][] = [['DE', 'Germany'], ['AU', 'Austria']];
 const myMap = new Map(myArray);
```

Fails to me with `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`
Am I doing something wrong here?

TS Version 3.9.9

Comment: The map constructor takes in array of pairs - `string[]` does not contain any length or positional information. Both `['DE', 'GERMANY']` and `['DE', 'GERMANY', '1', '2', 'foo']` are valid `string[]` - but only the first one is valid to use with a map constructor

Comment: Change the type of the array to `[string, string][]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you dig through the log, you'll see an error message of

> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

The problem is that `['DE', 'Germany']` gets automatically type-widened to `string[]` - an array of strings, which may have two elements, or one, or zero - but the Map constructor requires such entry arrays to have at least 2 elements. The type information that the number of items in the array is 2 gets lost.

I'd put the array declaration on the same line as the `new Map`:

```
const myMap = new Map([['DE', 'Germany'], ['AU', 'Austria']]);
```

Another option is

```
const arr: [string, string][] = [['DE', 'Germany'], ['AU', 'Austria']];
```

to show that the array actually does have 2 items in it.

Also note that you can't have a variable name start with a number - start it with something else, probably a letter.